# Ho to hide the " | " cursor symbol on click of the input box in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have used "readonly" property in the input box and it works fine for chrome browser but only in IE the cursor blinker is not hidden.
How can I hide the cursor blinker on click of the input box in IE?

```css
input#CC-prodDetails-quantity[readonly] {
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<input class="customQuantityStyle cc-numericField form-control" id="CC-prodDetails-quantity" type="text" readonly="readonly" data-bind="textInput: itemQuantity">
```

Comment: Fake duplicate marked by some users. This is different question than the mentioned duplicate one.

Comment: Can someone please help me fix this?

Comment: For IE, You can try to add onfocus="this.blur()" in your textbox. Example code: https://textuploader.com/15a6g This work around will show the cursor and hide it immediately.